# Can't Access User Defined Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Looks kind a stupid question but I have been stuck here for an hour.

I create a user defined function from Query window in SQL Server Management Studio with following statement:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION fnTest()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    return 123;

END
```

Function creates successfully and I can see it in SQL object browser as here:

[image]

But function isn't available for use in that database.

[image]
Interestingly when I try to Alter function by right clicking the function, function script loads with error message:

[image]

Can somebody give me an idea what I am missing here?

**EDIT:**
It really turned to be a stupid question. There is no error in function name, script, execution or Alter script. Everything is fine. Only SQL Editor is incorrectly showing error and I was confused by the editor error message. I apologies to everybody who spent time.

Answer (score 2):

Why didn't you specify `dbo.` when you *created* the function? My guess is that, because you didn't do so, the function was created in your default schema, which is not `dbo`.

- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

The only other possibility I can think of is that you are trying to execute the code in the context of the wrong database.